# How to pass object array containing both data and file through ajax and retrieve in mvc controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an object array like the following.

```
var array=[
{
    Name:"name",
    Address:"address",
    Files://array of files
},
{
    Name:"name",
    Address:"address",
    Files://array of files
}
];
```

I need to pass the array through ajax and retrieve it on mvc controller. I am not getting both data and file at the same time as array in controller.

I have used formData in case of single object.But in the case of array I don't know how.Anyone please help

my code..
model..

```
public class DataModel{
   public string Name{get;set;},
   public string Address{get;set;},
   public HttpPostedFileBase[] Files{get;set;}
}
```

Controller..

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddData(List<DataModel> data)
    {

       //code          
    }
```

ajax//

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/Mydata/AddData',
                    data: {data:array},
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (json) {
                      //some function
                    }
});
```

Comment: use form data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc

Comment: in case of object its ok.But how to pass object array instead??

Comment: You need to use `FormData` but you also need to generate the correct names - `[0].Name`, `[0].Address`, `[0].Files`, `[1].Name`, `[1].Address`, `[1].Files` etc

Comment: Send your files data as blobs. Converting form input to json string will not work because your form contains multiple files so try converting the each file as blob.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke How to make    FormData    of this array?

Comment: `FormData.Append('[0].Name', 'someValue');` etc. But where do these values come from. If you generate you view correctly the you can just use `var formdata = new FormData($('form').get(0));` as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you.You saved my time.It just worked..

Answer (score 0):

You can pass array by stringifying the array and pass it through data `attribute` of `ajax`.

```
var _myArray=JSON.stringify(array),
        $.ajax({
                //Rest of the code
                data: _myArray,
            });
```

Comment: JSON.stringify will change files in the array to {}.So it won't work

Comment: Who is it that keeps up-voting completely wrong answers?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke can you justify this is a wrong answer

Comment: Yes.If you stringify data, you must also use `contentType: 'json'` otherwise the `DefaultModelBinder` will not bind it, but you cannot send files using  `contentType: 'json'`. Suggest you try it your self.